# How to toggle font awesome class on click in Angular?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm trying to toggle the Font-awesome icon in angular.
The issue is that all the elements are getting toggled instead of the one that I'm clicking.

Here is the link to the code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uwnuu6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All elements are getting toggled because they are all reading the same variable in the component.

To have one variable for each item you need to create an array of items, and the store the favorite inside the object. Then, when you click it toggle the favorite for that item only.

Template:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        <td (click)="toggleFavorite(item)">
            <i class="fa fa-star" [className]="item.favorite ? 'ylw_yellow' : 'gry'">Favorite</i>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Component:

```
items = [
    {
        favorite: false
    },
    {
        favorite: false
    },
    {
        favorite: false
    }
]

toggleFavorite(item) {
    item.favorite = !item.favorite; 
}
```

Forked and updated code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dfeep7?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this, might be easier to put the items in a list of objects

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qaceyb?file=src/app/app.component.ts